# Trying to upload picture but does not save to server

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

something  lot simpler than the usual crap I post about!
Trying to create an 'Upload' button to allow user to upload pictures of themselves. The picture should then be renamed pid, and saved to the images folder..

I'm not sure why it isn't working, especially as firebug shows that fileField is being posted.

```
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['picID'])) {
    $pid = $_SESSION["pid"];
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "images/$newname");
    header("location: index.php"); 
    exit();
    }   
?>
```

**Picture upload field**

```
 <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='playerparent-profile.php?pid=<?=$pid?>'>
            <td><label>
          <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="picID" id="picID" value="<?=$pid?>">
                 <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="UPLOAD" />
        </label></td>
        </form>
```

Just trying to figure out what the heck I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Make sure that it's going to the right path, since without the slash, it will move it relative to the directory of the current script, rather than the directory of the page that the `POST` was sent from. I'm not sure on your file structure, but it's worth checking. Also ensure that `$_SESSION["pid"]` is set.

Comment: Lots of security vulnerabilities but what exactly is this `$pid` that keeps popping?

Comment: I believe you can't do that In a Server, Anyways what host are you using? Because you can't do that In GoDaddy!

Comment: hi @Arqetech, I'm using LCN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because this line is wrong I guess.
$pid = $_SESSION["pid"];
 you should use 
$pid = $_POST["pid"];

your $newname variable is not getting any name it will always store .png

hope this will help you

Comment: This, mixed with Chan's earlier answer got it working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the `$newname` variable of your PHP script. Since you are using double quotes, PHP would try to parse any variable that starts with "$" sign and end with space in that string. So in your case, PHP could be trying to look for the variable `$pid.jpg` and couldn't find one.

Try concatenation with single quotes instead:

> $newname = $pid . '.jpg';
>
> move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], 'images/' . $newname);